# ASP.NET MVC 4 VB hello world pain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I simply can't get the most basic MVC 4 site working.  I've downloaded a demo HelloWorld solution and it works, so the IIS side of things must be working.  I've gone through file by file and make sure they identical, but it still doesn't.  Please help.

I'm getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

My RouteConfig.vb looks like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing

Public Class RouteConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Default", _
            url:="", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "HomeController", .action = "Index"} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class
```

and my HomeController.vb looks like this:

```
Namespace re**********el
    Public Class HomeController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

And my Index.vbhtml looks like this:

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>
```

The whole folder set looks like this:

[image: Folder Set]

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has lots of "convention" type magic going on in the background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a fool I am.

Anyone else here:

```
defaults:=New With {.controller = "HomeController", .action = "Index"} _
```

Needed to be:

```
defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"} _
```